# Button style on disable

Tags: jquery

I need to style a submit button but I only need to apply a style is a button is disabled. I'm using jQuery but I'm not sure how to target it without using ID or class. I've tried something like this but it makes no sense, I think.....

```
$("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", "true").addClass("disabledClass");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`:disabled`](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/) pseudo-selector:

```
$("input[type='submit']:disabled").addClass("disabledClass");
```

However, this can also be done purly in CSS without any jQuery-hackery using [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors):

```
input[type='submit'][disabled] {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

---

Your original code selected all `input[type='submit']`, disabled them and then applyed the class `disabledClass` to them.